# Getting Error with an API data when connecting to JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, json, api

I've been trying to connect to An API using JavaScript for an assignment I've been given but couldn't get it through. Every time I'm trying to run a file it's showing blank HTML page, but on using different API link my code is working fine.

The errors it's showing:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://qa.parentlane.com/api/content-feed/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://www.parentlane.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
scripts.js:37

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://qa.parentlane.com/api/content-feed/ with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

```
const app = document.getElementById('root');

const container = document.createElement('div');
container.setAttribute('class', 'container');

app.appendChild(container);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://qa.parentlane.com/api/content-feed/', true);
request.onload = function () {

  var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach(feed => {
      const card = document.createElement('div');
      card.setAttribute('class', 'card');

     const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
      h1.textContent = feed.title;

      const p = document.createElement('p');
      feed.text = movie.text.substring(0, 50);
      p.textContent = `${feed.text}...`;

      container.appendChild(card);
      card.appendChild(h1);
      card.appendChild(p);
    });
  } else {
    const errorMessage = document.createElement('marquee');
    errorMessage.textContent = `Gah, it's not working!`;
    app.appendChild(errorMessage);
 } 
 }

request.send();
```

The result should pop-up a grid-like interface with the data in the JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's because the target host you're trying to query doesn't allow access
apart from itself. If I take a look at it's response header, it says:

```
access-control-allow-origin : https://www.parentlane.com
```

This means the script trying to query the api and the api would need to be on the same host.
Here's an in-depth article:

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS